# How to integrate TinyMCE with Sharepoint Online/SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Rich text fields aren't compatible with Chrome or Firefox and so I was trying to find an alternative solution to add formatting that will work with any browser. I've come across TinyMCE as a potential option but the instructions I can find apply to SharePoint 2007 and we use SharePoint Online and SharePoint Designer 2013. I've contacted Microsoft and their suggestion was to use IE because that's the browser SharePoint/InfoPath was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

It can be integrated, but I am not sure for what purpose you want it for. If you want it on a page, make a custom page layout, link tiny mce assets (js / etc) in the additional head, then on your page, add a script editor and put in the required markup ( flexible version ). Less effort requires just hard-coding it while you create the page.

Comment: We have several lists with corresponding forms. When a user clicks New item it loads the infopath form which includes several text fields. We'd like to have the additional formatting for these text fields that are embedded in the form.